# Copy a specific Range to a Word Document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

Instead of UsedRange, how do I copy the exact cell range from Excel to a Word document?

```
Sub export_excel_to_word()
    Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    obj.Visible = True
    Set newObj = obj.Documents.Add
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    newObj.Range.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    obj.Activate
    newObj.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean like `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z60").Copy` ?

Comment: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` copies the "used range" from the active sheet, but it's better to use `Worksheets("sheetname").` instead of `Activesheet.`

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/1055210-vba-format-size-word.html
and http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?62717-VBA-paste-special-to-Word For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: What do you mean by "the exact cell range"? How does it differ from the `UsedRange` you currently have? How should your code know how to identify the Range you want to copy? Perhaps you should apply a `Name` to the `Range` and use that to identify it?

Comment: The problem has been solved at Mr Excel.

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty easy to do.  Just set a reference to word and run the script below.  Of course, feel free to modify the script to suit your specific needs.

```
Sub ExcelRangeToWord()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
  (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J10")

'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

'Copy Excel Table Range
  tbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
  WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```