# VBA error with pasting from excel to word as picture

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a macro code that needs to filter specific data and copy schemes into word file. Currently I am using those two subs to copy and paste data. I use second sub right after first

```
Sub SheetOperation(typ_dev_ark, LayoutName, TS_dev)
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Select
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Cells(4, 1).Value = LayoutName
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Cells(3, 3).Value = "Techno Scheme No."
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Cells(4, 3).Value = TS_dev
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(typ_dev_ark).UsedRange
    rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

End Sub
Sub Paste(wdApp)
    wdApp.Activate
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdApp.Selection.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I always get an error for random entries at `wdApp.Selection.Paste` 4605 Run-time error. After pressing continue in debugger it always goes correctly, and even paste the thing it crashed on.

I have also tried this variation of code:

````
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Select
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Cells(4, 1).Value = LayoutName
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Cells(3, 3).Value = "Techno Scheme No."
    Sheets(typ_dev_ark).Cells(4, 3).Value = TS_dev
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(typ_dev_ark).UsedRange
    rng.Copy

End Sub
Sub Paste(wdApp)
    wdApp.Activate
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdInLine
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub```
And same thing happened.
````

Comment: Did you google the error 4605. *This method or property is not available because a document window is not active.* - I wonder if you need to replace `wdApp.Selection..` with something more specific..?

Comment: ```wdApp.Selection...``` seems fine. I inserted Call for Paste in SheetOperations and after error I try to paste again into word and for 99% error occurences there is succes in pasting data. Now I work on those errors that are not giving me results I want. It takes time since I have over 400 records. After I find more I will post here.

Comment: See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50379226/7446760 to see how it can be done without the use of `.Selection` and let us know if that fixes it.

Comment: I worked kind of good. I got sometimes error 4198 but fixed it by putting ```Sub Paste``` in ```Sub SheetOperations``` and giving a label on the start of sub SheetOperations. THen if error 4198 occured I just jumped back to the label and did whole sub again. It seems to work just fine. From what I found it is timing errors between VBA and System.I/O (clipboard). Thank you for your help @CLR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy a specific Range to a Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280867/copy-a-specific-range-to-a-word-document)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280867/copy-a-specific-range-to-a-word-document/50379226#50379226 This answeared my question